# Entity Framework will not update foreign key value to null

Tags: entity-framework-4

I cannot get the foreign key in my Entity Framework 4.3 code first database to be updated to null.

My view model:

```
public class AccountViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? CorporationId { get; set; } 
    public CorporationModel Corporation { get; set; }
}

var corporation = db.Corporation.Where(x => x.Id == model.CorporationId).FirstOrDefault();  // shows as null
account.Corporation = corporation;  // sets the value to null

db.Entry(account).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();  // does not save the null value in the FK field!!!
```

Any assistance would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: does the db value allow null entries? i guess so but thought i would ask

Comment: yes, it does. this is so puzzling to me!

Comment: also, if it is a foreign key, then it must be pointing to a value in another table, right? not sure if nullables would fit in with that?

Comment: It is pointing to an identity key in the other table. But shouldn't I still be able to null it out?

Comment: I don't think so. I could be wrong but - a foreign key has to be unique right? Usually points at the primary key of another table. For you to enter the null value in a foreign key field then in its primary table there must already be a null record for it. And you would only be able to set one of these records to null otherwise how would it know which record you were pointing at in the other table?

Comment: so i can't break that relationship unless the Corporation table had a 0 value for 'No Corporation'?

Comment: I manually did what you are trying.  Created a test table with an identity and a field that would serve as a foreign key.  Added the FK relationship between my primary table and test table. CHECK Inserted a record with a null value in the foreign key field. CHECK Replaced the null field with a key in the primary table.  CHECK  Changed it back to null, breaking the relationship.  CHECK   Make sure you schema is defined correctly and it SHOULD work.  But then you are working through the EF layer which may have it's own rules not equal to a real database ruleset.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must set the foreign key property to `null`. Setting the state to `Modified` only affects scalar properties (and the foreign key property is one of them but not the navigation property):

```cs
account.CorporationId = null;

db.Entry(account).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

If you don't have a foreign key property on `Account` you must load the account including the corporation:

```cs
var account = db.Account.Include(a => a.Corporation)
    .Where(a => a.Id == accountId)
    .SingleOrDefault();

if (account != null)
{
    account.Corporation = null;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I just figured it out and then read your post!  Yes, I had to create the account model by including the Corporation first. Thank you!

Comment: @Slauma, thanks for the answer - I was having trouble setting an associated property to null and using .Include() solved the problem.  Could you please explain why it is necessary to .Include() the associated property when all we're doing is setting it to null?  Sorry to dig up an old topic.

Comment: I know "thanks" is no accepted as a comment. But... Thanks!